# Lost the plug for my MagSafe 2 adapter, can I get it at Apple authorized repair sites?

Tags: magsafe

I lost the plug (duckhead) of my MagSafe 2 adapter, I know some people sell them on eBay, though I do not know if they are genuine/safe to use. Is it possible to buy them at Apple authorized repair sites?

Answer (score 1):

### Philips power plug

I use this for traveling as they are often cheaper than the original. You can plug any philips power plug in the adapter.

[image: Philips power plug]

*correct me if I am wrong, but I thought these were called philips power plugs*

Comment: I usually carry handmade short versions of these when traveling.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some Apple Authorized repair sites have them, but I would say it would be a long shot as most of those stores just sell 30-pin cables, lightning cables, and power bricks; nothing else. Your best bet is to go to your local apple store (if you have one nearby) or just order it from apples website or a more reputable place like Amazon. It is possible that the non genuine could work just fine but it could also break after a day or damage the power port.

Answer (score 0):

Most Apple Authorized Service Providers (AASP) will likely have some that they could sell.  Probably not new ones, but used ones or spares.

Answer (score 0):

The folks at Twelve South make the [Plug Bug](https://www.twelvesouth.com/product/plugbug) adapter that would fit the bill. It costs a bit more than an exact replacement would probably be. I borrowed one for a month and used it every day. No worries about how safe it is to use it and it fast charges my iPad mini. There is also an [international version](https://www.twelvesouth.com/product/plugbug-world) if you travel or live outside of the USA.